# Wake PC for Windows File History

Tags: networking, windows-10, wake-on-lan, xinetd

I have a PC which acts as a server for Windows File History running on all the Windows machines on my LAN (i.e., the clients all target a share on the server for storing their backups).

Rather than have the server run 24/7, I'd like to have it wake up on demand (I'm using File History's default every hour timetable).

I also have a Raspberry Pi running on the network as a DNS server. It also currently uses xinetd to watch for certain UDP packets to wake up a SageTV media server.

Is there a way to configure xinetd to watch for, say, destination unreachable packets related to a sleeping File History server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your bios if your nic support wake-on-lan packet, if so activate it then you will be able to wake your pc remotely with any soft that can send wakeonlan packet. WakeMeOnLan from NirSoft do that great for instance.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I know about wake-on-lan, and have set my NIC accordingly. This is an xinetd question. I currently have a service defined in xinetd which watches for a specific UDP packet and then sends a wake on lan signal to the PC. I want to be able to do something similar for the Windows File History service, but I don't know what protocols it uses to access network shares.